# How to delete a string from a file in bash

Tags: string, bash, shell

I want to delete a string from a file. This string is provided by the user. I tried the following command which didn’t work.

```
read -r input
sed -i '/"$input"/d' xyz.txt
```

I tried without double quotes("") as well. But it didn’t work.

Could you guys please help me?

Comment: You said you want to delete a string, but the command you've used deletes the whole line the string is in.  This is a different outcome than what you've expressed.  Which is desired?

Comment: in this case the whole line is the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -i "/$input/d" xyz.txt
```

but make sure `input` doesn't contain any regex special character.

`awk` with `index` function might be safer due to **non-regex**:

```
awk -v input="$input" '!index($0, input)' xyz.txt > $$.temp && mv $$.temp xyz.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that variables won't be expanded when put inside single quotes.

So you need to use double quotes:

```
sed -i.bak "/$input/ d" xyz.txt
```

The original file will be kept as `xyz.txt.bak` and the modified file will be `xyz.txt`.

If you do not want a backup:

```
sed -i "/$input/ d" xyz.txt
```